# Why filter and paging are not working together

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which has to filter and display the result by pages. On document ready everything seems fine. The items are separated by pages. If I click on checkbox or date it is filtering elements as I want, so it's working too. But the problem is that when the function filter items a new pagination is not creating. For example: I have 28 items. They display 3 pages - 10items/page. If I filter and the filter result is 12 items the function doesn't make 2 pages: 10 items on first  and 2 on second ... but everything is on the first page and the number of pages are not changing. This is my code:

[jsFiddle](http://jsbin.com/oqufun/2/edit)

I was trying to make the 'click' function 'live' like this:

```
$('label.check, .calendar a').live('click', function(){
   //the code
})
```

but I don't know why it is not working and it is braking.

I also tried to replace this `match`-es:

```
var pages = Math.ceil(match.length/page);
```

and

```
match.slice(first_item, last_item).show();
```

with `$('.widget.left:visible')` but it still didn't work.

So why is `live` not working? I think if it does, and give my match a live result, the rest will work but ... Can someone help?

edit: I don't know but my js doesn't run in the jsfiddle. I've tried both jsfiddle and jsbin but still doesn't. Sorry for that I don't know how to fix it but the code runs for sure. It is copy/pasted.

Comment: `live()` is deprecated in jQuery 1.7+. The alternative is `on()`.

Comment: It was good to know. That worked, but the problem seems to be different. Now whit on(). it does filter the items, but still doesn't apply the new pagination

Answer (score 0):

You said :

> but everything is on the first page and the number of pages are not
>   changing.

Because in your JSBin `$` is not defined. It means that JQuery is not defined, all others library also BTW.

I quickly add JQuery and JQuery UI, it is working the first time (when I click on americana for example). After it seems freezed. As I don't have all your dependencies, I stopped the debugging.

http://jsbin.com/oqufun/4/edit